# Why do we have that $\zeta = e^{i(2\pi /7)} \leftrightarrow 4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have the following written in my textbook:

> There is an isomorphism of $U_{7}$ with $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$ in which $\zeta = e^{i(2\pi /7)} \leftrightarrow 4$. Find the element in $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$ to which $\zeta^{m}$ must correspond for $m=0,2,3,4,5$ and $6$.

I would like to know how we get that $\zeta = e^{i(2\pi /7)} \leftrightarrow 4$? Using the one-to-one correspondence between $U_{n}$ and $n$, we have that if $\zeta^{i} \leftrightarrow i$ and $\zeta^{j} \leftrightarrow j$, then $(\zeta^{i} \cdot \zeta^{j}) \leftrightarrow (i +_{n} j)$. From this, I set up the equation $x +_{7} x \equiv 2$ since $\zeta^{2} = \zeta \cdot \zeta \leftrightarrow x +_{7} x \equiv 2$. However, this gives me that $2x \equiv 2 \pmod 7$. Then, $2x - 2 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$. But if $x = 4$, then $2(4) - 2 = 6$, which is not congruent to $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$.

I was hoping that someone could help me understand why we have $\zeta \leftrightarrow 4$?

Comment: I take it that $U_7$ means the order $7$ subgroup of the unit circle in $\Bbb{C}$. If so, then $\zeta \mapsto 4$ is an assumption, not something you have to prove. There are isomorphisms from $U_7$ to $\Bbb{Z}_7$ mapping $\zeta$ to any non-zero element. You are being asked to say how the isomorphism behaves on the other elements of $U_7$ if $\zeta \mapsto 4$.

Comment: @RobArthan: Thanks, I see now that $\zeta^{i} \leftrightarrow i$ happens to be an instance of an isomorphism that could exist.